# How do you increase the amount of inotify watchers in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

- `RUN cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` is `524288` on **Docker for Mac**
- `RUN cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` is `8192` on **Google Cloud Build's Docker**

See https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Cloud Build runs docker containers in privileged mode so you can simply add this step to your `cloudbuild.yaml`.

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current inotify file watch limit by executing:

`$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

Ubuntu Lucid's (64bit) inotify limit is set to 8192.
 so,you can make your limit permanent by,

`$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`

`$ sudo sysctl -p`